# Why Java-8 lambda need invokeDynamic byteCode to invoke an interface method

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

Hi I am trying to understand the advantages of using Lambda expression, where I heard usage of the invokeDynamic byteCode by JVM to execute lambda expression will improve the performance compared to XXXX(Sorry I don't know, it might be an Anonymous inner class).

My question is Why Lambda expressions need invokeDynamic byteCode.

For example:

```
public class LambdaTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MathOperation addition = (int a, int b) -> a + b;
        addition.operation(1, 2);
    }

    private static int operate(int a, int b, MathOperation operation){
        return operation.operation(a, b);
    }

    interface MathOperation {
       int operation(int a, int b);
    }
}
```

where the lambda expression `(int a, int b) -> a + b;` can be simply desugared into a static method like

```
   private static int lambda$1(int a, int b) {
       return a + b;
   }
```

which eventually can be invoked using `invokstatic` byteCode right?

More questions: What is the dynamicity lambda expression trying to achieve, when all the argument type, returns type are defined during the compile time itself.

For example: in the `lambda` expression `(int a, int b) -> a + b;` everything(`argument type, return type`) got defined during the compile time itself right?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The method holding the body of the lambda expression is *not* invoked via `invokedynamic`. The implementation of the functional interface is invoked via `invokeinterface`, just like any other interface method. The caller even doesn’t know whether an object implementing an interface has been generated for a lambda expression.

How this generated implementation of the interface invokes the synthetic method, is JRE specific, but usually it happens via an ordinary invocation (`invokestatic`, `invokevirtual` or `invokespecial`). Only the access rights follow different rules, i.e. the method can be invoked by the generated class despite being `private`.

The `invokedynamic` instruction is used for the *instantiation* of the interface implementation, so it allows arbitrary, unknown implementation classes, including classes, which do not exist at compile-time, but are generated at runtime. It also opens the possibility to return an existing instance instead of creating a new one, which is impossible for ordinary instance creation code.